# Extract strings containing digit characters with StringCases

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a large string like this:

```
string = {"text, 1998, TEXTDATA, text, 2007, NEXTTEXTDATA"};
```

Now I want to extract TEXTDATA and NEXTTEXTDATA. I tried to use `StringCases` and `Shortest`in combination with `DigitCharacter`like this:

```
StringCases[string, Shortest[DigitCharacter .. ~~ ___ ~~ ", "]]
```

but this of course yields only

```
(* {{"1998, ", "2007, "}} *)
```

So either there is a way to combine `DigitCharacter`with the FIRST comma (and then probably `Shortest`would work) or there is a way without `Shortest`?

Comment: do you mean you want to extract the uppercase text?

Comment: Or do you want to take the text appearing after a sequence of number and comma?

Comment: @Fraccalo yes but in this example, it is just uppercase for illustrative purposes...

Comment: @Fraccalo the text appearing between number+ FIRST comma and SECOND comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringCases[string, DigitCharacter .. ~~ ", " ~~ w : (LetterCharacter ..) :> w]
```

> {{"TEXTDATA", "NEXTTEXTDATA"}}

or

```
StringCases[string, NumberString ~~ ", " ~~ w : (LetterCharacter ..) :> w]
```

> {{"TEXTDATA", "NEXTTEXTDATA"}}

or

```
StringCases[string, ", " ~~ w : (LetterCharacter ..) ~~ EndOfString | "," :> w]
```

> {{"TEXTDATA", "NEXTTEXTDATA"}}

Comment: ```string``` has a very simple structure. What if  ```string``` contains other numbers and blanks? Is there a way to implement an exact rule: just (and only just) take the text between the 4-digit (its always a year but a string) and the SECOND comma AFTER this year-digit?

Comment: @M.A., you can try a more specific pattern like `StringCases[string, 
 Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}] ~~ ", " ~~ w : (LetterCharacter ..) ~~ 
   "," | EndOfString :> w]`

Comment: This appears to work only with "TEXTDATA" (again, sorry for my oversimplified ```string``` example). What if I have "A TEXT LIKE THIS" (with blanks)?

Comment: `StringCases[string, 
 Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}] ~~ ", " ~~ w : (Except[","] ..) ~~ 
   "," | EndOfString :> w]`?

Comment: Just a minor modification: ```StringCases[string, 
 ", " ~~ Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}] ~~ ", " ~~ 
   w : (Except[","] ..) ~~ ", " | EndOfString :> w]``` This ensures that Strings like "P1675" are kicked out. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

For the moment, it seems to suffice just to understand the selection criterion as to find all the substrings consisting of upper letters. To convey that information, one can use [`RegularExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) or [`CharacterRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CharacterRange.html) to construct the string pattern.

```
string = {"text, 1998, TEXTDATA, text, 2007, NEXTTEXTDATA"};
stringpattern1 = RegularExpression["[[:upper:]]+"];
stringpattern2 = CharacterRange["A", "Z"] ..;
StringCases[string, stringpattern1]
StringCases[string, stringpattern2]
```

both with the same result

> {{"TEXTDATA", "NEXTTEXTDATA"}}

---

If one has to work by specifying the environment of the substrings rather than the information of the target substrings themselves, the string pattern is also accessible as

```
stringpattern3 = RegularExpression["\\d, ([^ ,]+),?"] -> "$1";
```

which is saying "picking out whatever parenthesized characters except a blank or a comma, following a substring consisting of a digit, a comma, and a blank, and simultaneously followed by a comma or nothing (no more than one comma)".

Comment: (+1) I like `stringpattern3`

Comment: @user1066 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
string = {"text, 1998, TEXTDATA, text, 2007, NEXTTEXTDATA"};
list = StringSplit[string[[1]], ", "];
filter = RotateRight[StringMatchQ[list, NumberString]];

Pick[list, filter]
```

> {"TEXTDATA", "NEXTTEXTDATA"}

Answer (score 1):

```
StringCases[string, 
RegularExpression["[0-9]{4},\\s([A-Z]+)"]:> "$1"]
```

> {{TEXTDATA, NEXTTEXTDATA}}

(In Mathematica, `$1` [refers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RegularExpressions.html) to the capturing group (within the parentheses)).

```
string2 = {"text, 1993,         TEXTDATA, text, 2007, NEXTTEXTDATA"};

StringCases[string2, 
RegularExpression["[0-9]{4},\\s+([A-Z]+)"]:> "$1"]
```

> {{TEXTDATA, NEXTTEXTDATA}}

**Edit**

For " just (and only just) take the text between the 4-digit (its always a year but a string) and the SECOND comma AFTER this year-digit",  maybe:

```
StringCases[string, 
RegularExpression[",\\s+[0-9]{4},\\s+([A-Z]+)"]:> "$1"]
```

> {{TEXTDATA, NEXTTEXTDATA}}

**Edit 2**

Answering a comment by the OP:

" What if [...] "TEXT DATA" or "NEXT TEXT DATA"?

Such a case is easily handled by a RegExp by modification of the capturing group:

```
string3 = {"text, 1993,         TEXT DATA, text, 2007, NEXT TEXT DATA"};

StringCases[string3, 
RegularExpression["[0-9]{4},\\s+([A-Z\s]+)"]:> "$1"]
```

> {{TEXT DATA, NEXT TEXT DATA}}

**Edit 3**

For a more complex string:

```
string4 = {"text, 1993,         TEXT-DATA, text, 2007, NEXT/TEXT (2004) DATA"};
```

The regex may be modified as follows (one way!):

```
StringCases[string4, 
RegularExpression["[0-9]{4},\\s+([A-Z0-9\s-()/]+)"]:> "$1"]
```

> {{TEXT-DATA, NEXT/TEXT (2004) DATA}}

Comment: See also my comment to the answer of @kglr: What if I have "TEXT DATA" or "NEXT TEXT DATA"?

Comment: @M.A. Such a case is easily handled by regexp. See edit

Comment: very impressive but (for me!) the solution from kglr is more understandable...

Comment: Maybe. But (borrowing heavily from @Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ) `StringCases[string, RegularExpression["[0-9]{4},\\s+([^,]+),?"]:> "$1"]` is very understandable to me, and seems to tersely and specifically meet all your requirements.

Comment: See my last comment on @kglr: you solution finds also Strings containing a 4-digit number such as "P1675". It should only detect years which are speficially defined by ", YEAR," (e.g. ", 1978,"). However, I am sure you can also handle this in your solution...

Comment: Substituting `RegularExpression["[^A-Za-z][0-9]{4} ..." ` (four-digit number that cannot be preceded by any letter, uppercase or lowercase), `RegularExpression["\\s[0-9]{4} ..." ` (four-digit number preceded by a single whitespace) or `RegularExpression[",\\s+[0-9]{4} ..." ` (comma, followed an one-or-more whitespace(s), followed by four-digit number) are possible solutions to that scenario (see my answer).