# Extract specific string from a list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

My question is similiar to previous questions (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214873/extract-strings-containing-digit-characters-with-stringcases/214884?noredirect=1#comment549623_214884) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149436/extract-string-words-from-string)), although the issue is maybe somewhat more complicated:

I have a list with strings like this:

`list = {{"text1, text2, 2003, text3"},{"text1, 1994, text2"},{text1, text2, text3 2014, text4}}`

I now want to extract the part of the string which contains the 4-digit Number (or in this case its a year number) AND is separated by the commas so that the outcome is:

`{{"2003"},{"1994"},{"text3 2014"}}`

I have tried this one:

`StringCases[#,", " ~~ w : (___ ~~ Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}]) ~~ ", " :> w] & /@ list`

but this extracts always the part from the first comma in each string

many thanks for you suggestions

Comment: @user1066: I dont understand your question, but the answer by kglr seems to solve it!

Comment: @user1066 thx for that hint! I have edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposal in the original question can be made to work by replacing `___` with `Except[","]...`:

```
StringCases[", "~~w:(Except[","]...~~Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}])~~", " :> w] /@ list

(* {{"2003"}}, {{"1994"}}, {{"text3 2014"}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Map[StringTrim @* Select[StringContainsQ @ Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}]]] @
 StringSplit[Flatten @ list, ","]
```

> ```
> {{"2003"}, {"1994"}, {"text3 2014"}}
> ```

You can replace `Select[...]` with `Cases[_?(StringContainsQ@Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}])]` to get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

```
StringCases[#, RegularExpression["([^,]+[\\d]{4})"]:> StringTrim["$1"]]&/@list//Catenate

(* {{2003}, {1994}, {text3 2014}} *)
```

where:

```
list = {{"text1, text2, 2003, text3"},{"text1, 1994, text2"},{"text1, text2, text3 2014, text4"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"text1, text2, 2003, text3"}, {"text1, 1994, text2"}, \
{"text1,text2,text3 2014,text4"}}

patt = WordCharacter ... ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
   Repeated[DigitCharacter, {4}];

list // Map[StringTrim@*First@*StringCases[patt]]
```

{{"2003"}, {"1994"}, {"text3 2014"}}